How to scrape this webpage?
I need to make a web scraper of this webpage with R and rvest:
https://www.australianwhiskyauctions.com.au/lot-350169/chichibu-2016-single-heavily-peated-1st-fill-bourbon-cask-6240-for-whisky-abbey-2022
I was able to work with all the web page data, except for final bid and reserve price.
When I search for them in the page code I find it:
<div class="itemPrice"><div class="priceDesc">
    <div class="innerPriceWrap">

        <span class="priceLabel">                Final Bid:        </span>            <div class="itemPriceWrap" v-if="bid_value > 0" :class="bidStatusClass">
                [%% bid_value|multi_currency %%]
            </div>
        <div class="itemPriceWrap" v-else>
            [%% 0|multi_currency %%]
        </div>
    </div>

    <span class="priceLabel" v-if="max_bid">
            Max Bid:
    </span>

    <div class="itemPriceWrap" v-if="max_bid">
        [%% max_bid|multi_currency %%]
    </div>

    <div class="innerPriceWrap">
        <span class="priceLabel" v-if="reserve_met">
                Reserve Met
        </span>
        <span class="priceLabel" v-else>
                Reserve Price
        </span>

        <div class="itemPriceWrap" :class="bidStatusClass" v-if="!reserve_met">
            [%% reserve_price|multi_currency %%]
        </div>

    </div>

</div>    </div>
</div>

As you can see the final bid is as [%% 0|multi_currency %%] and reserve price is as [%% reserve_price|multi_currency %%].
I dont what to do, could someone please help me?

The bid value and reserve values are stored in a JSON file.  You can access the lot id and thus the JSON file this way:
library(dplyr)
library(rvest)
library(jsonlite)

#read page
url <- "https://www.australianwhiskyauctions.com.au/lot-350169/chichibu-2016-single-heavily-peated-1st-fill-bourbon-cask-6240-for-whisky-abbey-2022"
page <- read_html(url)

#find lot id - the bid-form element under the div with class=bidControlsRow
lotid <- page %>% html_elements(" div.bidControlsRow bid-form") %>% html_attr("lot-id")

#access the JSON file with the bid information
biddata <- jsonlite::fromJSON(paste0("https://www.australianwhiskyauctions.com.au/bids/", lotid))
biddata$bid_value

The biddata variable is a list containing the requested information.

That data is being filled in by Javascript.
If you want to scrape the fully-rendered contents (like you would see in a browser), you need to run the Javascript, somehow.
I'm not familiar with how to do this in R or rvest, but hopefully this points you in the right direction.
Some details:
That [%% foo %%] syntax is some kind of templating language. If you put a breakpoint on one of those elements (eg: the "Next auction ..." countdown), you will see that it gets filled in by Javascript. In partcular, it is this blob of code: /sites/auction_template/min/a.js?_b969b706
I realize that's not terribly helpful — you would need to reverse-engineer that code to understand it. But hopefully this helps you recognize such things in the future.
